# WPF Binding and Including String Literal

Tags: c#, wpf

I am doing a very simple thing which is to display the text like this in a Label:

```
LastName, FirstName
```

My View is binded to the ViewModel which contains the FirstName and LastName properties. I want to do something like this:

```
<Label Content="{Binding LastName}, {Binding FirstName}"
```

Of course the above does not work. So, I concatenated the FirstName and LastName and returned as a FullName from the ViewModel and bind it like this:

```
  <Label Content="{Binding FullName}"/>
```

Is the above a better approach? Since, now I have to do the same thing with City, State.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`MultiBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.multibinding(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
   <Label.Content>
            <TextBlock>
              <TextBlock.Text>
                <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0} + {1}">
                  <Binding  Path="City" />
                  <Binding  Path="State" />
                </MultiBinding>
              </TextBlock.Text>
            </TextBlock>
     </Label.Content>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although I think that is a lot of typing if I have to do the same for 5-6 controls.